# Add the field_data_field_void_delete table values with views_get_view()

Tags: views

In my project, I am using `views_get_view()` to get some values. It doesn't include the data of the *field_data_field_void_delete* table I required. I need to apply the `field_void_delete_value = 0` filter to its data.

Is there any way to achieve this?

The code I am using is the following.

```
$myview = views_get_view('purchase_tracking');
$myview->set_display('block');
$myview->set_current_page($page);
$myview->set_items_per_page($limit);
$myview->set_arguments(array($person_id));
$myview->execute();
$table_data = $myview->result;
echo '<pre>';
print_r($table_data);
die;
```

I also need filtering the node table basing on the value of its *status* column; I want to get those rows where status is 1.

I added a pagination to the code. So adding the filtering in `views` function will get the correct output.